# Prepend zero to byte

Tags: java

I'm reading file and I want to print byte value in 2 digits if it is less than 10 (example if byte=1 it should disply byte=01), I don't want to compare it like this:

```
    if(byte<10){
        stringBuffer buf= new stringBuffer();
        buf.append("0"+byte);
    }
```

is there any built-in method to do this, just like the format function in vc++?

Comment: ooh, so many identical answers, so little to pick between them....

Comment: Yes, you asked the question yesterday. Why are you asking it again today in a separate question?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but I would just like to point out that buf.append("0"+byte); is not very good.  Why use a StringBuffer if you are just going to do String concatenation anyway?  What you should do is buf.append("0").append(byte);

Just a little tip for using StringBuffers, from me to you ;)

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
String twoDigits = String.format("%02d", myByte);
```

It's a lot closer to the C way of doing things rather than having to instantiate your own formatter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("00");
buf.append(df.format(byteArray[i]));
```

Obviously you just instantiate it once outside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("00").format(9));
```

prints 09 for me.

Answer (score 2):

See [java.util.Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 1):

The 'a' is 10 in hexadecimal format.

So change your format strings from "%02x" to "%02d"

Comment: but you definitely don't want hexadecimal format, it seems. Is the problem with %02d that you get 1000 instead of 0010 ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class

Answer (score 0):

```
byte b = ...
System.out.println(String.format("%02x",b));
```

Answer (score 0):

For "small" values of b this should be fine:

```
String s = "" + b;
while(s.length() < 2) {
   s = "0" + s;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so convenient with java syntax... But here is a way... May be you need to find equalant of right for java

buf.append(right(("00" + byte),2))